# An alert can be accepted when loading page with selenium on internet explorer?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, alert, pageload

I'm trying to get an url with selenium and node.js, but when the site has an alert I can't accept it on Internet Explorer.

index.js

```js
    require('iedriver');
    const express = require('express');
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    let ie = require('selenium-webdriver/ie');
    function start(params) {
        start_server();
        let options = new ie.Options();     
          options.ignoreZoomSetting(true);
    
        let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('internet explorer')
        .withCapabilities(options)
        .build();
    
        let site="http://127.0.0.1:3000/";
        driver.get(site)
        .then(()=>{
            return driver.wait(webdriver.until.alertIsPresent(),10000)
            .then(()=>{
                let alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                return alert.accept()
                console.log("go on");
            })
        })
        ;
    }
    const start_server=()=>{
    
        const app = express();
        const PORT = 3000;
      
        app.use(express.static('static'));
            
        app.get('/', function(req, res){
          let options = {
            root: path.join(__dirname+"/../static/")
          };
          
          let fileName = 'index.html';
          res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              log(err);
            } else {
              console.log('Sent:', fileName);
            }
          });
        });
        
        app.listen(PORT, function(err){
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
        });
          
      };
      start();
```

The site to open has an alert when page is loading, like this:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="loading.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       
</body>
</html>
```

loading.js

```
alert("accept before start");
```

This has to work on Internet Explorer.

When running , after 5 minutes it shows this

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Timed out waiting for page to load.
at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\d\adhoc\node\copyimgwz\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:517:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\d\adhoc\node\copyimgwz\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:642:13)
```

and stops like this

[blocking alert on ie with selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlZKn.png)

Please, any idea how to accept that alert with selenium?

**EDIT**

I found out a solution, adding this line it's already working fine

```js
options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(true);
```

Comment: Well, it looks like your problem has been solved. You can post the solution as an answer, and mark it when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, adding this line

```
options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(true);
```

in this section

```
let options = new ie.Options();     
options.ignoreZoomSetting(true);
options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings(true);
```

Aparently, On internet explorer you need to activate this characteristic to let you work.